# Remove duplicates in SQL Result set of ONE table

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

Afternoon/Evening all,

I'm looking for the final touches to the below query. I need to remove the duplicate occurrences of a column in a particular row. Currently using the below SQL:

```
SELECT CBNEW.*
FROM CallbackNewID CBNEW 
INNER JOIN (SELECT IDNEW, MAX(CallbackDate) AS MaxDate 
FROM CallbackNewID 
GROUP BY IDNEW) AS groupedCBNEW 
ON (CBNEW.CallbackDate = groupedCBNEW.MaxDate) AND (CBNEW.IDNEW = groupedCBNEW.IDNEW);
```

My result set looks like the below

```
ID     RecID  Comp  Rem Date_               IDNEW   IDOLD   CB? CallbackDate
138618  83209   1   0   2012-03-16 12:40:00 83209   83209   2   16-Mar-12
138619  83209   1   0   2012-03-16 12:40:00 83209   83209   2   16-Mar-12
110470  83799   1   0   2011-07-27 11:46:00 83799   83799   10  27-Jul-11
110471  83799   1   0   2011-07-27 11:46:00 83799   83799   10  27-Jul-11
```

This however gives me duplicate values in the CallBackDate and IDNEW Column because in the table there are some different Primary Keys with the same IDNEW and CallbackDate values.

If I dump this result into Excel, I can just use remove duplicates on the first ID column, and the problem's solved.

But what I want to do is make sure my result only includes the FIRST instance of the ID column, where IDNEW and CallbackDate are duplicated.

I'm sure I just need to append a tiny piece of SQL, but I'm stuck if I can find the answer so far.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `MIN(ID)` to the inner query and then adding it also on the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT CBNEW.*
FROM CallbackNewID CBNEW 
INNER JOIN (SELECT IDNEW, MIN(ID) AS MinId, MAX(CallbackDate) AS MaxDate 
FROM CallbackNewID 
GROUP BY IDNEW) AS groupedCBNEW 
ON (CBNEW.CallbackDate = groupedCBNEW.MaxDate) 
   AND (CBNEW.IDNEW = groupedCBNEW.IDNEW)
   AND (CBNEW.ID = groupedCBNEW.MinId) ;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8c20/2)</kbd>

Comment: i dont understand why you need min to remove duplicates?

Comment: he asked for the first id for the group that he does with IDNEW. I thought of MIN to do that. Do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Yes i feel so unless he thinks the output your query provide is correct

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you think it is wrong? The output surely looks correct to me if you look at the results on sqlfiddle and the sample data he has on his question.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me only some 4,411 records rather than the 11,337 results I'm expecting. Using the original SQL I get 11,364 results. Dump to Excel, 43 Dupes to remove.

Not sure what value would equal the 4,411 but I'm assuming it has something to do with the MIN statement.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is happenning. If you group by idNEW and get the max(callbackdate) and min(id) for those elements, you should get the right amount of records. can you add a few more examples to sqlfiddle and share it in your question to see what is wrong in the query?

Comment: In fact, I'm assuming here, I'm looking for the max unique value of dates in a set of 50,000. The 4,411 entries are probably that there is only 4,411 Unique entries within the set.

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've added a little more to the fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1ce6/1/0

The New 3 entries appear in the fiddle results, but they do not appear in my MS Access result set.

Comment: I can't see why they shouldn't appear. Do you see any reason?

Comment: I'm completely flummoxed, I'm trying to identify where it's getting its incorrect count of 4,411 from, and I can't find that number by messing around with the set in Excel, counting duplicates on all the cell columns.

Comment: In excel is a bit tricky to remove duplicates based on tree columns (id, newid and date). If you remove duplicates based on only one column, you might end up with more things than you needed.

Comment: I'm 100% confident on the amount of records i'm expecting to see. As I look at it the temp table 'groupedCBNEW' appears to have the problem. There's only 4411 records in it. Am I missing something when I ask it to be created in the SQL?

Comment: Furthermore, if I create a simple query like this:

    'code' SELECT Min(CBNEW.ID) AS MinOfID, CBNEW.IDNEW, Max(CBNEW.CallbackDate) AS MaxOfCallbackDate
FROM CallbackNewID AS CBNEW
GROUP BY CBNEW.IDNEW;

Then I get exactly the results I need, albeit without the additional fields.

Comment: You are right, that is very weird. If you inner join with a subset it should give you that subset, not less than that. I can't really understand how that could give you less results. sorry.

Comment: I thought you had it pegged, so I deleted my answer. I've just undeleted it in case @user2953562 might find it useful. You get to keep my upvote, anyway.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather "brute force" approach. It just takes the results of your original query and does `Min()` on [ID], `Max()` on [Comp] and [Rem], and `GROUP BY` on everything else:

```sql
SELECT 
    Min(t.ID) AS MinOfID, 
    t.RecID, 
    Max(t.Comp) AS MaxOfComp, 
    Max(t.Rem) AS MaxOfRem, 
    t.Date_, 
    t.IDNEW, 
    t.IDOLD, 
    t.[CB?], 
    t.CallbackDate
FROM 
    (
        SELECT CBNEW.*
        FROM 
            CallbackNewID CBNEW 
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT IDNEW, MAX(CallbackDate) AS MaxDate 
                FROM CallbackNewID 
                GROUP BY IDNEW
            ) AS groupedCBNEW 
                ON (CBNEW.CallbackDate = groupedCBNEW.MaxDate) 
                AND (CBNEW.IDNEW = groupedCBNEW.IDNEW)
    ) t
GROUP BY 
    t.RecID, 
    t.Date_, 
    t.IDNEW, 
    t.IDOLD, 
    t.[CB?], 
    t.CallbackDate;
```

It might not be terribly elegant, but if it works....

Comment: Thanks, I attempted, but resulted in 3 more records than I would expect, the dupes are found in the IDNEW column.

Comment: @user2953562 Is the sample data in the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1ce6/1/0) complete enough to illustrate the problem?

Comment: This addresses what was wrong with my query. I didn't saw it at first. The MIN and MAX in the same group by were returning invalid rows that were ignored in the outer JOIN. This should do it. Can you post the 3 records you talk about in sqlfiddle? and all the rows with same date, id and idnew.

Comment: @user2953562 Or, you could create a new SQL Fiddle with 4 records: the 3 "extras", plus the one you ultimately want to keep. That might help us isolate what you actually want to GROUP BY.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, and added the 6 dupe rows, (3 to keep). I'd want the first occurrence of any dupe. Well, i say first, i mean, any singular occurrence.

Thanks again.

Comment: @user2953562 Okay, if it's the last 6 rows you're talking about then they appear because COMP or REM is different. So you want to GROUP BY everything *except* ID, COMP and REM? If so, do the COMP and REM values have to come from the same row as the MinOfID, or can they be `Max()` or `Min()` aggregates?

Comment: You sly fox. Good eye. Always take the Max on those two values.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server, I think you are looking for the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Something like this should help you get what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    X.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DBNEW.IDNEW, DBNEW.MaxDate) [row_num]
        FROM
            CallbackNewID CBNEW 
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT
                    IDNEW,
                    MAX(CallbackDate) AS MaxDate
                FROM
                    CallbackNewID 
                GROUP BY
                    IDNEW
            ) AS groupedCBNEW ON (CBNEW.CallbackDate = groupedCBNEW.MaxDate) AND (CBNEW.IDNEW = groupedCBNEW.IDNEW)
    ) X
WHERE
    X.row_num = 1
```

Comment: Access does not support `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm being rather archaic and building in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    (SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDNEW ORDER BY CallbackDate DESC)
                          AS [row_num]
     FROM CallbackNewID 
    ) A
WHERE
    A.row_num = 1
```

Comment: Access does not support `ROW_NUMBER()`.