# Remove semi-duplicate rows from a result set

Tags: sql, sybase, duplicates

I have a logging table (TABLE_B) that is updated via triggers from a main table (TABLE_A).  The trigger operates whenever any field on TABLE_A is inserted/updated.  We need to pull a report out that shows only a subset of updates on TABLE_B - ie the user is only interested in the fields:

```
ID
STAGE
STATUS
UPDATE_DATE
```

I need to remove sequential duplicates from the result set, ie, suppose the following entries exist in TABLE_B:

```
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|ID  |STAGE|STATUS|UPDATE_DATE|
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|7    |9     |2012-12-25 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|4    |2     |2012-12-24 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|4    |3     |2012-12-23 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|4    |2     |2012-12-22 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|4    |2     |2012-12-21 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|4    |3     |2012-12-20 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
|4567|4    |2     |2012-12-19 |
+----+-----+------+-----------+
```

From the bottom, I need to extract rows 1,2,3,5,6,7 - omitting row 4 only: I have 2 entries at rows 3 & 4 that are duplicates (row 4 has been triggered into TABLE_B because of an update to some other field in TABLE_A, but it's stage/status combination hasn't altered therefore it can be ignored).

So, when I discover that the next row in a result set is a duplicate (and only the next row) of the current row, how can I either remove it from the result set, or neglect to select it in the first place.  I'll be performing the operation using a stored proc - will a cursor be involved in this?

Sybase 12.5, though the syntax is very close to SQL Server.

Comment: Does your version of Sybase support the `lead()`/`lag()` functions?

Comment: Not sure Gordon - but I think I have the answer based on another thread.  Posting shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at a similar question on StackOF:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774273/remove-duplicates-in-sql-result-set-of-one-table
```

I think this answers the question:

```
select id, status, stage, min(updated_date)
from TABLE_B
where id = <someValue>
group by id, status, stage
```